# XSL Transform extracting min and max dates

Tags: date, xslt, minmax, nodesets

I'm trying to extract min and max dates from an XML source. I'm getting a nodeset into my variables and I need the actual date value within the nodes and can't find how to get it.

Source XML:

```
<Info dataSource="source">
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121211</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130112</EndDate>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121211</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130112</EndDate>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121211</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130112</EndDate>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121218</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130114</EndDate>
</Detail>
</Info>
```

The XSL code:

```
  <xsl:if test="//StartDate != '' and //EndDate != ''">
    <xsl:variable name ="startDate">
      <xsl:for-each select="//StartDate">
        <xsl:sort select="StartDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name ="endDate">
      <xsl:for-each select="//EndDate">
        <xsl:sort select="EndDate" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable> 
  </xsl:if>
```

The dates are formatted correctly to support the sorts and retrieval, the issue is once the variables are populated I can't find how to access their values:

[image]

Comment: This all sets up to get the diff between the two values, the days in period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 2.0 you have `min` and `max` functions which do the work for you.  XSLT 1.0 doesn't have these functions, but you can cheat by doing this (may be rather inefficient for large inputs, but it works):

```
<xsl:variable name="startDate" select="string(//StartDate[not(. > //StartDate)])" />
```

and similarly for the endDate.  The trick here is that you're looking for the StartDate *d* for which there is no other StartDate that *d* is greater than.

Comment: Thanks, Ian.  I should have specified, this is XSLT 1.0.

Comment: The inputs won't ever be too large, the full file I pulled this example data from is only 339 lines, and most of the time there will be between 1-4 instances of the servicePeriod dates. You're example/idea is awesome, but I'm pulling an empty string with it. DOH, I need to update the names, being lazy.....